# Remove <span> tag Using Regex Only C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex

I want to remove only that  span tag where class is "neighborhood". And I do not want to remove rest of the span tags. I want to do only with regex, i dont have other choice.

```
  <span class="latitude">34.008253</span>
  <span class="longitude">-118.414593</span>     
  <span class="neighborhood">Neighborhood: Clarkdale</span>
```

Please help me out. Thank You

Comment: `@"<span\s class="neighborhood"*/>|*</span>"` won't compile

Comment: I think you have an extra space after \s.

Comment: Replace the '"' with '' and then run your check minus the quotes

Comment: -1 for specifying the solution instead of asking for one.

Comment: And why have you used a pipe in between opening and closing tags?

Comment: Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) for this.

Comment: @CR41G14, it would probably be better to correct the string literal rather than the input; just change it to `@"<span\s class=""neighborhood""*/>|*</span>"`. (Note that this still doesn't even come close to a solution for the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
@"<span class=""neighborhood"">[^<]*</span>"
```

That will work assuming that no other tag is closed before span. Also, HTML allows a lot of whitespace, so you might need to adjust to that.

Comment: Can you also help me on for my post  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/abbdf68d-d325-4b6f-abf9-120ca0ed4840